# Trace inequality related to the product of three matrices

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, matrix-norms

> Given rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and positive definite matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, prove that $$-\mbox{tr}(A^TBA) \leq -\sigma\|A\|^2_F$$ where constant $\sigma > 0$ may depend on $A$ and $B$.

I have developed a rudimentary proof for the same, however I want to know if my reasoning is correct or if someone can improve upon my proof or provide a better proof. My proof is as follows:
Since $A^TBA$ is a positive definite matrix, $tr(A^TBA) \geq ||A^TBA||_2$, therefore:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
tr(A^TBA) &\geq ||A^T||_2||B||_2||A||_2 \\
-tr(A^TBA) &\leq -\rho(B)||A||^2_F/r
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In my reasoning above, I have utilized the fact that $||A||_2 \leq ||A||_F \leq \sqrt{r}||A||_2$ where $r$ is rank of $A$ matrix. My main contention is if $tr(A^TBA) \geq ||A^T||_2||B||_2||A||_2$ holds? 
Also $tr$ represents trace and $\rho(.)$ represents spectral radius and thus according to my 'not-so-rigorous' proof $\sigma=\rho(B)/r$. 
Can any expert provide a better/concrete proof for $-tr(A^TBA) \leq -\sigma||A||^2$.
Lastly, thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: Use `\|` for norms, rather than `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=Q\Lambda Q^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation. By the tracial property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$, we get
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{tr}(A^TBA)
&=\operatorname{tr}(A^TQ\Lambda Q^TA)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda Q^TAA^TQ)\\
&\ge\lambda_\min(B)\operatorname{tr}(Q^TAA^TQ)\\
&=\lambda_\min(B)\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)\\
&=\lambda_\min(B)\|A\|_F^2.
\end{aligned}
So, you may pick $\sigma$ as the minimum eigenvalue of $B$.

The inequality $\operatorname{tr}(A^TBA)\ge\|A^T\|_2\|B\|_2\|A\|_2$ is wrong. E.g. for every $0<t<1$, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^TBA):=\pmatrix{0&1}\pmatrix{1\\ &t}\pmatrix{0\\ 1}=t<1=\|A^T\|_2\|B\|_2\|A\|_2.
$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your valuable inputs, my main concern was, if, I can write: $tr(A^TBA) \geq ||A^T||_2||B||_2||A||_2$, because everything else follows from this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks once again, but is this true- $\|A^TBA\|_2 \geq \|A^T\|_2\|B\|_2\|A\|_2$ for PSD matrices? I mean isnt the inequality other way round? Pardon me for asking this question!

Comment: Oh OK! Now I see the the point. I just can't figure out how you went from 2nd inequality to 3rd. That's all. Rest everything else is easy to understand in your proof. Once again thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: @Amardeepmishra For any PSD matrix $P$, we have $\lambda_i(B)p_{ii}\ge\lambda_\min(B)p_{ii}$ because $p_{ii}\ge0$. It follows that $tr(\Lambda P)=\sum_i\lambda_i(B)p_{ii}\ge\sum_i\lambda_\min(B) p_{ii}=\lambda_\min(B)\sum_ip_{ii}=\lambda_\min(B)tr(P)$.

Comment: I got it! Thanks once again

Comment: @Amardeepmishra $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1(B),\ldots,\lambda_n(B))$ is the diagonal matrix that contains the eigenvalues of $B$ on the diagonal. The symbol $p_{ii}$ denotes the $(i,i)$-th entry of $P$, i.e. the $i$-th diagonal entry of $P$.

Comment: Now it is crystal clear! Thanks a lot for your rigourous proof